# Angular Authorization header is null on CROSS DOMAIN API call. Why?

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, authorization

I have an Angular (1.3.8) SPA with a factory method that is attempting to add a basic authorization header before making a cross-domain API call.
The API is an ASPNET WEB API but has CORS totally enabled. The API is using basic auth message handler

The problem is that in the first call to the API there is no AUTHORIZATION header at all even though the code making the API call looks like this:

```
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic  blah...';

    $http.get('http://my-webapi-url').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
     }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('error ' + status);
    });
```

The API is not receiving an AUTHORIZATION on the initial call, and is rejecting the call with 401 of course. Why isn't there an AUTH header from the start?

Comment: what do you see when inspect the request headers in browser console?

Comment: When watching the network traffic from the browser do you see an OPTIONS request before the GET request?

Comment: Enzey is asking the relevant question here.  It turns out that there is an OPTIONS request before the GET request, and the server API was responding to this OPTIONS request with a 401 challenge.  Fortunately, I have control of the API service as well, so I altered it to NOT issue a 401 challenge if the request was "preflight" (i.e. OPTIONS).  This solved the problem.